# Import ViewController from main target to test target in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Trying to import my controllers to run tests. I need use my controller in the test target but don't know how to write the #import statement the right way. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: #import "YoueController.h"
Are you sure this is your problem?

Comment: I mess up trying to write the full path of the class and then found this solution. Sorry.